# Why is this code added to MetadataTypesHandler.ProcessRequest

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Why is this code added to `MetadataTypesHandler.ProcessRequest()` in ORMLite for ServiceStack?

```
httpRes.ContentType = "application/x-ssz-metatypes";
var encJson = CryptUtils.Encrypt(EndpointHostConfig.PublicKey, json, RsaKeyLengths.Bit2048);
httpRes.Write(encJson);
```

Looks like it's signing the page but the content type is non-standard.

Comment: I'm really just checking that it's not a "left over" from someone's hacking.

Answer (score 1):

That code lives in ServiceStack project itself, it doesn't have nothing to do with OrmLite. That code is essentially the beginning [part of this future feature](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/4459003-add-add-service-reference-functionality) to provide enough metadata suitable for being able to code-gen DTOs locally as a substitute for sharing dlls. Because it involves code-gen from a remote source it's encrypted to give us better security/control on how and what gets code-gen'ed.